# AIX library calls to get thread info / status

Tags: c++, multithreading, aix

Are there any AIX runtime library calls that I can use in C++ on AIX to monitor the status of threads associated with the running process? I'm trying to resolve a crash-on-shutdown problem that I believe is being caused by the program exiting before all threads have joined.

I appreciate that in a multithreaded environment, it's not going to be easy to accurately log the status of the threads as they may well have changed between reading the status and displaying it, but anything - however crude - would be useful as a first step in tracking this down.

Comment: there is a strong AIX support community on ITtoolbox.com under groups. ( I have no financial interest there, I am only a registered user). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You said "crash-on-shutdown'... do you mean a system crash with a crash dump?  If so, then you have tons and tons of data.  If you need, I would start a system trace with a large buffer.  After the system crash and reboot, you can suck the trace buffer from the dump using trcdead.  Plus you have the state of the system.

It should not be that goofy threads cause a system crash.

Comment: The process crashes when instructed to close down gracefully. It's not a system crash. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Shoot.  I had a long reply typed out with that assumption and then deleted it.  Let me redo that for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a system trace facility.  I have not used it much (any?) from an application but it is thread safe.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/trace_facility.htm#yg3100thri

and

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/tracing.htm?resultof=%22%61%70%70%6c%69%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%22%20%22%61%70%70%6c%69%63%22%20%22%74%72%61%63%65%22%20

If this is a very complex application, I would wire up real trace hooks and develop a trace format file.  It will be worth the time spent.  What follows below is a cruder method.

The way I would probably track this down is to wire up a home grown trace or log facility.  In the code, sprinkle calls to the log routine.  Then go back and examine the core file, dig out the log buffer, and that will tell you the sequence of log points that you hit.

This will likely be an iterative process where you add a few points, then figure out you need more points in a particular part of the code and add log points there.  Try again.  repeat.

The log routine is very simple actually and leverages one of the atomic ops.  I'm using fetch_and_add.

```
long array[4096];       /* some power of 2 in size is my preference */
unsigned int index;     /* int -- not a long */

/* trace 5 words each time. */
void log(long *a, long b, long c, long d, long e)
{
  /*
   * the 5 equals the number of args.  The 4095 is one less than the
   * size of the array.  You can use mod if you want.  Also, note that
   * there are flavors of fetch_and_add for different sized
   * variables.  Pick the one that matches the size of index.
   */
  int i = fetch_and_add(&indx, 5) & 4095; 

  /*
   * at this point, array[i] ... array[i+4] have been effectively
   * reserved.  The time taken between the fetch_and_add and updating
   * the array does not need to be atomic or locked.  The only
   * possible exception is you don't want the log to wrap within this
   * time but that would be very unlikely.
   */

  array[i] = *a;
  array[i+1] = b;
  array[i+2] = c;
  array[i+3] = d;
  array[i+4] = e;
}

/* your original code spinkle calls to log */
int whatever(long arg1, int arg2)
{
  log("WHT1", arg1, arg2, 0, 0);

  foo = apple + pie;
  bar = whisky + good;
  dog = nice + pet;
  cat = meow;

  log("WHT2", foo, bar, log, dog);

  /* ... */
}
```

The trick of the first argument is so that when you get your core file and dump out array, you can dump it out as hex and also as text.  From the text output you can quickly see which log points are being called.  If you have a 64 bit application, instead of limiting yourself to 4 characters, you get to use 8.

Note that the value of index is key in the core file.  That tells you the last log point that was hit.  Then step backwards through the log array to see the previous log points.